# macOS Sierra: Python segmentation fault 11

Tags: python, macos, tkinter

I am trying to make a Python text editor. When trying to run this code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from tkFileDialog import *

filename = None

def newFile():
    global filename
    filename = "Untitled"
    text.delete(0.0, END)

def saveFile():
    global filename
    t = text.get(0.0, end)
    f = open(filename, 'w')
    f.write(t)
    f.close()

def saveAs():
    f = asksaveasfile(mode='w', defaultextension='.txt')
    t = text.get(0.0, END)
    try:
        f.write(t.rstrip())
    except:
        showerror(title="Oops!", message="Unable to save file...")

def openFile():
    f = askopenfile(mode='r')
    t = f.read()
    text.delete(0.0, END)
    text.insert(0.0, t)

root = Tk()
root.title("TextEditor")
root.minsize(width=400, height=400)
root.maxsize(width=400, height=400)

text = Text(root, width=400, height=400)
text.pack()

menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar)
filemenu.add_command(label="New", command=newFile)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=openFile)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save", command=saveFile)
filemenu.add_command(label="Save As", command=saveAs)
filemenu.add_separator()
filemenu.add_command(label="Quit", command=root.quit)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=menubar)

root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Python quits and I get this error

`Segmentation fault: 11`

I am on Python 2.7.10 and it does the same thing with Python 3.5.2

I don't think my code is the problem, but I put it in anyway because it's a possibility.

Comment: what version of tcl do you have? `print(root.tk.call('info', 'patchlevel'))` versions `'8.5.7'` or  `'8.5.9'` are unstable for macosx.

Comment: I have 8.5. I used these commands `local/bin $ tclsh
% puts $tcl_version
8.5`

Comment: ok.... can you run the command `print(root.tk.call('info', 'patchlevel'))` since that will give me the patch version which is what I need to know.

Comment: "WARNING: The version of Tcl/Tk (8.5.9) in use may be unstable.  Visit http://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/ for current information." [the warning IDLE raises if you have an unstable version of Tcl](https://github.com/tadhgmister/cpython/blob/master/Lib/idlelib/macosx.py#L78)